# Maximum number of vertex disjoint $S-T$ paths

Tags: graph-theory

> How is the maximum number of vertex disjoint $S-T$ paths defined ?

Given a graph $G=(V,E)$ with $S,T\subseteq V$ An *$S-T$ path* is a path with one endpoint in $S$, the other endpoint in $T$, and all interior vertices outside of $S\cup T$. Any vertex in $S \cap T$ is a trivial $S-T$ path.

So what is the maximum number of $S-T$ paths, do we first fix $2$ points, one in $S$ the other in $T$ and then count all paths having disjoint internal vertices, and we do this for any $2$ points and choose the pair with maximum such paths.

Or

say $S=\{s_1,s_2\dots\}$ and $T=\{t_1,t_2,\dots\}$ then we select $s_i-t_j$ paths in such a way that $$(s_i-t_j\  path) \cap(s_k-t_l\  path)=\emptyset$$ and count these

Answer (score 1):

Definitions aren't written in stone, and this kind of question is hard to answer without context to tell what the author meant. However, the second definition seems more natural.

Consider a bipartite graph $G$ with $V = \{u_1, \ldots, u_n, v_1, \ldots, v_n \}$ and $E = \{ u_1v_1, \ldots, u_nv_n \}$. Let $S$ be $\{ u_1, \ldots, u_n \}$ and let $T$ be $\{ v_1, \ldots, v_n \}$. Clearly there are $n$ disjoint paths between $S$ and $T$. However, if you try to apply the first definition you gave, for every pair of vertices there are either $0$ or $1$ disjoint paths between them, so that would tell you that the number of disjoint $S-T$ paths is $1$, which is silly.

The way I would think about it is that I would identify all the vertices in $S$ to make a new vertex $s$, and then identify all the vertices in $T$ to make a new vertex $t$, and then count the number of disjoint $s-t$ paths in this new graph. This is (mostly) equivalent to the second definition you gave, provided you're careful about how you count trivial paths.